# Adding more than one DIT

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have posted this question in [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108184/having-problem-with-adding-more-than-one-dit) but it is considered off-topic and people suggest that I should post it here so I am posting it here.

I have an `openldap` server up and running on `ubuntu 14.10` and I have managed to successfully add a `DIT` into it using following `ldif` :

```
dn: olcDatabase=hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
olcRootPW: secret
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
```

For the sake of testing multiple `DITs` I tried to add another database using another `ldif` :

```
dn: olcDatabase=hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=example1,dc=com
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=example1,dc=com
olcRootPW: secret
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
```

First it seemed that everything went well but when I tried to search my first database I got an error that said:

```
result: 80 Other (e.g., implementation specific) error
text: internal error
```

Being confused about this error I ran `slapd -d` and here's what I got :

```
bdb(dc=example,dc=com): BDB0060 PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
```

I even installed `db-utils` and ran `db_recover` with no success.
The question is what's wrong with my `openldap` server ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the primary error is that you used the same `olcDbDirectory` for both DITs. Try to use different directories to store the data (you will likely have to wipe the current data and start over).

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I have read somewhere in openldap documents (couldn't recall where though) that It is "sensible" to define different olcDbDirectory for different DITs  and as far as I understand it is not mandatory to do so. BTW I will give it a try and let you know if you are right :)